# Every View stick together when loop LayoutInflater

Tags: android, xml, view, layout-inflater

I have a layout problem. my code have a LayoutInflater set the following xml as layout, and will loop few time to show my school time table. Eventhough i have set the relativelayout's marginBottom and Top to 50dp, but why every layout still stick together?

here's the xml:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_part"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/table_day"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/table_date"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/table_day"
            android:textSize="@dimen/table_day_size" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/table_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="14dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/table_date"
            android:textSize="@dimen/table_date_size" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/center_part"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/left_part"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/left_part"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left_part" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/center_part1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/table_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="@string/table_time"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="@dimen/table_timelocationclass_size" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/center_part2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/center_part1" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/table_subject"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/table_subject"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="@dimen/table_subject_size" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/center_part3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/center_part2" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/table_lecturer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="@string/table_lecturer"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textSize="@dimen/table_lecturer_size" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/right_part"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/center_part"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/center_part"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/center_part" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/right_part1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/table_location"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="@string/table_location" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/right_part2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/right_part1" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/table_class"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="@string/table_class" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the print screen:

[image]

here is the loop:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_table);
ll.removeAllViews();

        //set table layout
        for(int i=0;i<tableRow.size();i++)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View perClassTable = inflater.inflate(R.layout.perclass_table, null);
            TextView table_day = (TextView)perClassTable.findViewById(R.id.table_day);
            TextView table_date = (TextView)perClassTable.findViewById(R.id.table_date);
            TextView table_time = (TextView)perClassTable.findViewById(R.id.table_time);
            TextView table_location = (TextView)perClassTable.findViewById(R.id.table_location);
            TextView table_class = (TextView)perClassTable.findViewById(R.id.table_class);
            TextView table_subject = (TextView)perClassTable.findViewById(R.id.table_subject);
            TextView table_lecturer = (TextView)perClassTable.findViewById(R.id.table_lecturer);
            table_day.setText(date[i].substring(0, 3));
            table_date.setText(date[1].substring(4,13));
            table_time.setText(time[i]);
            table_location.setText(loca[i]);
            table_class.setText(clas[i]);
            table_subject.setText(subj[i]);
            table_lecturer.setText(lect[i]);

            //testing
            ll.addView(perClassTable);
        }
```

Comment: Can you show how you implement the margins? From what I understand you don't want these boxes touching, you want just a 50dp margin between each?

Comment: ya, i want to set some space between 2 boxes. Any ideas? =S

Comment: Can you post the code with the loop where you use the `LayoutInflater` to inflate that layout file?

Comment: okay, i updated~ =)
tableRow.size() actually mean how many class is need to show.

Comment: Does this snippet of code, at the end of your `for` loop makes a difference? `LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  lp.topMargin = 100;
  lp.bottomMargin = 100;
  ll.addView(perClassTable, lp);`

Comment: Your code is works very well! Thx @Luksprog 
is that LinearLayout.LayoutParam mean create a LinearLayout outside the RelativeLayout with the params?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set some `LayoutParams` with some margins for your inflated view at the end of the `for` loop:

```
    //...
    table_subject.setText(subj[i]);
    table_lecturer.setText(lect[i]);

    // set some proper LayoutParams for the inflated View which is going to be added
    // to the ll LinearLayout
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    // set some margins to distance the rows 
    lp.topMargin = 100; 
    lp.bottomMargin = 100; 
    // add the inflated view with to ll with the LayoutParams above.
    ll.addView(perClassTable, lp);
}
```

The `LayoutParams` is a special class designed to be use with a `ViewGroup` subclass which generally holds layout attributes like width/height, margins, layout positioning rules etc.
Also, you could improve the layout file by removing all those wrappers `RelativeLayouts` and set the `TextViews` directly in the parent `RelativeLayout`. If the number of rows is big you may also want to have a look at the `ListView` widget as galex said in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

A `RelativeLayout` evaluates it's children from top to bottom.  So, if you use something like `android:layout_above="@+id/table_date"`, it must come after `table_date`.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_part"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/table_date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="14dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/table_date"
        android:textSize="@dimen/table_date_size" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/table_day"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/table_date"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/table_day"
        android:textSize="@dimen/table_day_size" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here, I have swapped the textviews.

Comment: Sorry @Simon, maybe my question is not very clear. I mean every rectangle box's top and bottom is touching. =(
i need to set some space between them.
But thx ya!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a list to me, look into [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html).
It will even recycle views if you implement your adapter correctly!